# JavaFX lookup ToggleGroup class by it's name

Tags: javafx

When I need to get Button class I do next:

`Button B = (Button)scene.lookup("#ID");`

How can I lookup ToggleGroup class?

Comment: Using lookups like that is really bad practice. Why do you need a lookup at all?

Comment: I need to embed external fxml document inside my JavaFX program. But the external fxml always different. The only way I can to work with it - is using IDs. IDs comes in script file with fxml.

Comment: Can't you just inject everything you need into a controller? That's the recommended approach.

Comment: No. I do not know what fxml I will load. So I can not prepare controller class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lookups are generally not very robust, and as you point out in your question you can't use them to access elements that are not nodes in the scene graph (such as toggle groups). Normally, you should inject elements into the controller.

If you are dynamically generating the FXML, or for some other reason can't create a controller class, you can access the FXML loader's namespace. This is a map that you can use to look up objects via their `fx:id` attribute from the FXML.

So if you have an FXML file with

```
<VBox>
    <fx:define>
        <ToggleGroup fx:id="myToggleGroup"/>
    </fx:define>
    <children>
        <RadioButton text="A" toggleGroup="$myToggleGroup"/>
        <RadioButton text="B" toggleGroup="$myToggleGroup"/>
        <RadioButton text="C" toggleGroup="$myToggleGroup"/>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

then you can retrieve the toggle group with

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(fxmlURL);
Parent root = loader.load();
Map<String, Object> fxmlNamespace = loader.getNamespace();

ToggleGroup toggleGroup = (ToggleGroup) fxmlNamespace.get("myToggleGroup");
```

You can, of course, do the same with the scene graph elements. There is an advantage to doing things this way instead of using CSS lookups, as the namespace will be fully populated as soon as the FXML file is loaded. (CSS lookups will only work once CSS has been applied.)

Also, since the `namespace` is just a map, you can dynamically find the `fx:id`s that are defined by calling `namespace.keySet()`, so there is no need to know a priori what ids might be defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot. All works! You forget to cast class to ToggleGroup in last assignment